# Why do transform iterators not implement operator->?

Tags: c++, boost, iterator, boost-iterators

While transform iterator implementations such as `boost::transform_iterator` are certainly useful, all implementations I've found seem to share one common weakness: they only provide `operator*`, and no `operator->`.

Given a transform function returning a reference, implementing `operator->` is straightforward.

Given a transform function returning by value, implementing `operator->` using a proxy should also not be a problem.

Why is it deemed preferable to provide only an `operator*`, and no `operator->`? Is the use of a proxy here any different from e.g. `std::vector<bool>`?

**Update:** Here's a very simple proof of concept to demonstrate how such a proxy object could work (hard-coded for `std::string` type):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <string>

class StringProxyDemo {
public:
    class Proxy {
    public:
        Proxy(std::string value) : _value(std::move(value)) { }
        std::string *operator->() { return &_value; }
    private:
        std::string _value;
    };

    Proxy operator->() { return _function(); }

    StringProxyDemo(std::function<std::string()> function)
    : _function(std::move(function)) { }

private:
    std::function<std::string()> _function;
};

int main() {
    StringProxyDemo demo(
        []() -> std::string {
            return "Hello, World!";
        }
    );
    std::cout << demo->size() << std::endl;
    std::cout << demo->c_str() << std::endl;
}
```

[Run on Ideone](http://ideone.com/ZkvUmX)

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth Given a transform function returning by value, the lifetime of the returned value would need to be hoisted to the calling scope. Thus the iterator's `operator->` could return a proxy object containing a copy of the returned value and an `operator->` returning a pointer to that copy.

Comment: Without seeing any code, might it be something to do with the recursive nature of `operator->` ?

Comment: @RichardCritten The problem is precisely that the code is missing in existing implementations of `transform_iterator` :) I added a simple proof of concept to show how I would imagine such a proxy object to work.